# Are NDB KeyProperty attributes equivalent to ancestor keys in queries?

Tags: python, app-engine-ndb

I think the answer is "yes" but I want confirmation.  If one ndb.Model is a "child" of another ndb.Model (through a one-to-many relation), can I drop the KeyProperty and simply use ancestor keys in queries?  For example:

```
class Parent(ndb.Model):
    pass

class Child(ndb.Model):
    parent_key = ndb.KeyProperty(Parent)
```

Can I simply remove `parent_key` and instead use `.filter(ancestor=parent_key)`?

[update]: The following question was answered, but the previous question (regarding queries) remains.

> At a deeper level, are ancestor keys "equivalent" to KeyProperty
>   values?

Answer (score 2):

No.

A key can be composed of many segments, for example:

```
ndb.Key('Parent', 'grandma', 'Parent', 'dad', 'Child', 'you')
```

This is stored in the `key` for the object and getting the parent just discards the last two segments and gives the rest. So for the above:

```
ndb.Key('Parent', 'grandma', 'Parent', 'dad')
```

The `KeyProperty` has nothing to do with this, it's just a property owned by the entity.

So if you were to create:

```
child = Child(parent=ndb.Key('Parent', 'grandma', 'Parent', 'dad'))
```

you'd find that

```
>>> child.key
ndb.Key('Parent', 'grandma', 'Parent', 'dad', 'Child', None)
```

while

```
>>> child.parent_key
None
```

Comment: Assuming all child entities were created with an ancestor, is .filter(parent_key=key) better or worse than .filter(ancestor=key) where key=ndb.Key('Parent',...) ?

Comment: It depends on your definition of better or worse. Ancestor queries do lookups within entity groups and so make queries consistent immediately, but are also limited to 1 QPS within an entity group.

Comment: Does the 1 QPS limit apply to ndb.get_multi() or entity.put()?  Or only to Child.query(...)?

Comment: @BrentWashburne I'm sorry, it applies to writes to this entity group.